# What's the difference between from and on vs on

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

> Although few facts exists regarding the life of the Native American
>   named Sequoia, the information that is available paints a colorful
>   picture of this man **on the plains**.

Its one of those SAT Questions where you try to find the best phrase for the **bolded** words. The answer was "from and on the plains" but I don't get why the "from and on" is necessary opposed to just "on".

Comment: What were all the choices?

Comment: They were [No Change], [of the plains], [from and on the plains], and  [on which the plains].

Comment: They're all wrong. Sequoyah was neither "from", "of" nor "on" the plains--he was born in Tennessee and lived in Tennessee, Alabama and Arkansas until he moved in his 60s to the Indian Territory in what is now Oklahoma, outside the beginning of the Great Plains.

Comment: The western half of Oklahoma is part of the Great Plains. for what it is worth

Comment: Sorry, Semin Yoon, but it looks as though you signed up for the wrong course.

"Although few facts exists regarding the life of the Native American named Sequoia, the information that is available… " will always be suspect. That’s more true of "… this man on the plains" and more clearly true for “… from and on”.

The usual - overwhelmingly recognised - phrase is “*of* the plains” and anyone trying anything else else risks ridicule, unless he has strong justification… which leaves your SAT Q in the ridiculous camp, don’t you think?

Comment: As people have said, this is really weird. The facts and questions are wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the premise that there is an answer that can be considered correct by all.

Answer (score 1):

A man *from* the plains might be someone who was born there but now lives an entirely different lifestyle.

A man *on* the plains might be a visitor to them, and is probably also not be living the lifestyle described.

A man who is both *from and on* the plains likely describes a plains native who is continuing the live the lifestyle associated with that area, and so that is the person who is described.

Comment: A 'man on the plains' sounds unidiomatic. A 'man from and on the plains' sounds pretentious and weird. Then there's StoneyB's claim for factual inaccuracy. Let's face it, this question (and this question) should be binned.

Answer (score 0):

A "colorful picture" would most likely tell us about the man and about his lifestyle.  If the information illuminated only his biography, then "man from" might work, but if it also describes *how* he lived - what he ate, how he stayed warm in winter - it would tell us about his life "on" the plains.  If we assume the information reveals both biographical and anthropological data, "from and on" seems best.